# How to detect taps vs tilts in analog stick input

Tags: input, platformer, joystick, polling

I'm trying to detect when a player taps vs tilts the analog stick. Ultimately, I'm trying to implement controls like Super Smash Bros. Melee. On top of this, I also want to incorporate an input buffer so the controls aren't so strict.

#### Implementation

This implementation was before I considered adding input buffering.

1. Poll for input events via `SDL_PollEvent`.
2. Update the game controller state with input events.

As the game controller's state was updated, it would also calculate changes in the analog stick and determine if the player tapped/smashed the stick or not. The game controller object also determined if face buttons were being pressed or held.

This implementation seems to work, but it doesn't maintain the order of inputs.

Q. Does the implementation above sound like a good way to detect taps vs tilts?

Q. If I used an input buffer, would it make sense to scan the buffer and label a sub-range of inputs as a tap or tilt?

- With that, a state machine could respond to the label instead of the raw analog stick events.
- This also helps with large amounts of analog stick events.

Q. Is it a bad idea to store the state of the game controller in an input buffer instead of individual analog stick events and button events?

Comment: We generally can't tell you how a specific game's version of a feature was implemented. Most of us never worked on that specific game, and even those who might have are often restricted by NDAs from sharing specific details. What we can do is help you implement *your game's* version of this feature. Can you clarify what specific problem you have with your two attempts so far, so we can help you improve them? Sharing sample code and specific test cases that don't behave as desired can help you get focused answers that accurately solve those issues and work within your approach.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try providing more details about my implementation so people can provide suggestions.

Comment: "Does that sound like a good/bad idea" / "Would it make sense to...?" sounds like polling for opinions. I find questions here generally get better answers when they focus on specific outcomes instead. When you implement your input management as you describe, does it meet your needs? If so, you're very likely golden, without needing to wait for Internet strangers to weigh in. If it doesn't meet your needs, what specific problem do you observe, or what aspect of the implementation feels unsatisfactory to you? Clarify that, and we can focus answers on solving those specific issues.

Comment: I guess I am polling for opinions :-). I'll continue to experiment with what I have. You can close this question or leave it here in case someone wants to respond.